# Android - Is it possible to get error "description" from MediaPlayer error code?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, error-code

MediaPlayer error listener looks like this:

```
public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {...}
```

Is it possible to get a meaningful message from `int what` or `int extra`, that I could display to user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From line [2881](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/media/java/android/media/MediaPlayer.java#L2881) of [Android Media Player Source Code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/media/java/android/media/MediaPlayer.java) there are error code defined which description of Error Code occurred.

In-case of [MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/media/java/android/media/MediaPlayer.java#L2881) "Unspecified media player error." is defined to indicate that there is no description available of the error.